# Sql query to clean up junk record

Tags: mysql, sql

Somehow a table is having junk data, need to clean it up and generate a new table.

I think it should use case or some row_number over, tried a few, failed.

Database is mysql.

original table:

```
Student Registration    Course
John                    CS
John    2018            
John    2017            
Peter   2019            MATH
Mary    2016            MATH
Mary    2016            CS
```

The rule is, if we have duplicate records for a student, merge them together, for Registration, take max of year. If no any columns is missing, like Mary. order by Course asc, take first record. so the result will be :

```
Student Registration    Course
John    2018            CS
Peter   2019            MATH
Mary    2016            CS
```

Comment: Let's add `Mary 2016 CS` into the mix. Now what should the result look like?

Comment: if this case, order by Course asc, take first one, CS

Comment: rule updated. @Strawberry, you raised a good question. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want aggregation:

```
select student
     , max(registration) as registration
     , min(course) as course
  from original
 group 
    by student;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT Student, MAX(Registration), MAX(Course) 
                              -- or MIN(Course) if you want the first alphabetical
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY Student
```